# Spark/Synapse Optimal handling huge gzipped xml file (+600mb compressed size)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-synapse

For a task we need to process huge transactional xml files which are gz(ipped). Each line in the uncompressed file can be interpreted as its own xml record.

When working with small files like 100 MiB this works fine. The moment à collect() is performed on the huge input file it tends to fail OOM and the jvm crashes.

As this is a compressed (gz) file it can not be processed in parallel (AFAIK).

I was thinking about

- using the toLocalIterator() to split it first up into smaller packets of 200K xml entries which are distributed to the other nodes for their cost om processing. Apparently the toLocalIterator() does also the collect() first (to test)
- Other option is to use the some kind of index value and filter on it ("index > 5000") and set the limit(5000) to simulate paging through the 2 Million or more entries.

But I have no clue to what I should pay attention to parralize. Any tips are welcome.

- Settings to pay attention and how to apply them in Azure Synapse etc.
- how to push the read xml over the nodes to be processed in their executor/tasks.
- could streaming a single file be an option?
- any tips are welcome

Currently my code is done in scala due the fact the java libraries are easily accessible to convert the xml to json and extract the values I need.

Many thanks in advance (also for reading this)

Comment: What kind of transformation are you trying to apply to the xml files? Why is it necessary to `collect` the data during the process?

Comment: You can certainly stream process gzipped XML in Java / Scala using a combination of java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969713/java-xml-parser-for-huge-files . I don't know enough about Spark and Azure Synapse to give you specific instructions on how to combine the two, sorry. GL!

Comment: The purpose is that we can store the whole dataset as a consumable thing (json) in a datalake V2 storage as parquet files. 
Depending on the needs (context) we'll have separate queries. The original xml "records" their structure is partially fix and partially variable depending on the context of the data. The data itself is converted to JSON as this is easier to access (some scala code using the SAX Java libs).

I'll give the suggestions a try.
Currently we have something working where the whole stream is repartitioned into 32 partitions, but no parallelism yet.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR suggestion:

Step 1. Increase driver memory and test

Step 2. Increase executor memory and test if first step fails

Slightly longer version:

The fact that it gives OOM on `collect()` operation doesn't indicate whether it is OOM on `spark.read` operation or `df.collect()`
Spark scheduler will run the DAG when it encounters an `Action` but not when it is a `Transformation`.
So if `collect` is your first action, it is at that point it actually runs the DAG and the OOM may even be on read but manifesting as OOM on collect

Spark UI will provide insights on where the OOM happens

You are right that uncompressing gzip wont be parallelised. On read operation, it will use a single executor and even a single core. So I would increase executor memory until there is sufficient memory to gzip the whole file into memory - not just to the exact file size, leave the usual 400MB / 0.7% buffer.

If the error is indeed happening on the `collect()` operation, then you need to sufficiently increase driver memory.

Your app will not be parallelised at `read`. Your app will not be parallelised at `collect()`
You app can be parallelised during the transformations in between them and you can force the parallelisation to the extent you want to tune it by repartitioning your dataframe / dataset / rdd further.

Finally, I would consider again whether you do need the collect or whether you can store the output as a number of partitioned files?

Comment: Thanks. I'll give the info a try

Comment: @VincentDegrave Some feedback would be good whether that helped or not?

Answer (score 0):

I think the zipped file is always going to be a bottleneck so one alternative is to unzip it and see if that helps.  I would also consider loading up the xml to a table in Synapse (which can deal with gzipped files).  This would have the effect of unzipping it, you could then pass it into a Synapse Notebook with the `synapsesql` method, eg in Scala:

```
// Get the table with the XML column from the database and expose as temp view
val df = spark.read.synapsesql("yourPool.dbo.someXMLTable")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("someXMLTable")
```

You could process the XML as I have done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68163601/1527504) and then write it back to the Synapse dedicated SQL pool as an internal table:

```
val df2 = spark.sql(""" 
SELECT
    colA,
    colB,
    xpath_string(pkData,'/DataSet/EnumObject[name="Inpatient"]/value') xvalue
FROM someXMLTable
""")

   
// Write that dataframe back to the dedicated SQL pool
df2.write.synapsesql("yourPool.dbo.someXMLTable_processed", Constants.INTERNAL)
```

This would ensure you are keeping things in parallel, no `collect` required.  NB there are a couple of assumptions in there around uploading the gzipped files to a dedicated SQL pool and that the `xpath_string` does what you need which need to be checked and confirmed.  The proposed pattern:

[image: Synapse XML pattern]

Comment: Any update on this?  What happened to the bounty @StijnWynants?

Comment: Thanks, i'll also give this a try.

Comment: regarding the " loading up the xml to a table in Synapse". Can you give an example on this, i'm searching but not clear if this has to be loaded into a linked database (which is accessible via a gateway onprem) or some cosmos/other instance?

Sorry for the novice question and many thanks in advance! (not used to Azure and cloud stuff yet)